# LinkedIn Job API with OAuth authentication using C#

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

We've develop a new project of posting Jobs directly to LinkedIn using Job Posting API from within our web application. Our web application is developed in C#.

There is sample code available in LinkedIn Developers for posting of Jobs in C# [HERE](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/code-sample-posting-job-c)

I replaced sample `"API_KEY"` or `"API_SECRET"` with my original key or secret. But when i execute this code it always give me  error : `remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden`
I think In order to post jobs, LinkedIn uses OAuth signed calls. OAuth-based authentication is very new for me. so i can not understand reason of this error.

How can i resolve it?

Bunch of Thanks for your valuable help...!!

Comment: Have you checked the response headers and body, usually it will contain more information about the error.

Comment: I think so. Can you please give me a sample header for that?